# Why don't people, in general, take any initiative?

Tags: management

I run a software team and am just a few months into the job. One of the things I have noticed is that nobody wants to handle certain tasks and when they spot bugs or things in need of updates they just ignore them. They dodge responsibility and belong on the subreddit notmyjob. I am mostly looking for a generalized answer for why people dodge responsibility and ignore problems as I don't want to reveal too much about my company as some of them also use Stack Exchange.

Comment: What do they say when you talk to them about it?

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane they claim they did not see it or did not know anything about it. Even when one of them posted a comment on github about updating it for a personal project.

Comment: " I am mostly looking for a generalized answer for why people dodge responsibility and ignore problems "  Some people are lazy.

Comment: @noinitiative, a generalized answer won't help you. If you want a reliable answer here, provide details like the one in your comment, in your question. The fact that you want an answer without dedicating more time to develop your questions implies you may have to improve in setting examples.

Comment: If one of my managers brought this to me during a 1:1, I'd respond by asking them to define initiative. Then I'd ask them how **I** demonstrate it. Initiative comes from the top down. If your people don't behave that way then you haven't created a space for it or made it a priority. In addition, I'd say you probably don't exhibit it where they can see it. You are their example. How are **you** showing initiative?

Comment: I don't mind the fact that this is a generalized question (on the contrary, I believe such questions are much more useful to others than overly-specific questions), but a much more actionable version of the question would be "How do I get subordinates to take more initiative and responsibility". It would probably touch on similar points, but the latter focuses on what you can actually do to address it (e.g. "management systems ignore non-client driven work" versus "budget for and reward valuable non-client driven work").

Comment: @noinitiative , it's completely commonplace that the vast majority of software engineers are (in a word) ... useless!  (This isn't because people are bad or evil - it's because software is incredibly difficult.) Steve Jobs famously remarked that there is a vast talent gap between the majority of programmers and the handful of worthwhile ones ...  one good programmer is worth 25x the typical programmer.  What you're saying is the norm on all teams, companies, groups.

Comment: Again, Steve Jobs simply agrees with you.  Article:  https://www.fastcompany.com/1836987/listen-steve-jobs-payoff-great-employee  **"the difference between ... superb programmers vs. average ones is 25:1"**

Comment: "when they spot bugs [...] they just ignore them" - did they really ignore them or maybe rather have a quick look and realized that they have to touch some ancient code that they'd *really* prefer to not touch? Is whatever tool you use to track bugs maybe not amazing, so it feels like too much overhead to even report them?

Comment: Because with initiative you implicitly take responsibility, and by taking responsibility you also take a risk of failure. If your company is a really bad company, failing might mean losing your job or being demoted, which is adding another risk on top. The question is, is there a high risk of really hard consequences in case of a failure? Are the benefits of taking an initiative equally good to motivate people to take the initiative and associated risks?

Comment: @noinitiative, If people don't see what the negative consequence of not fixing bugs will do to them, they will not be eager to fix bugs. As a leader, you can tell them that the bugs will effect the performance of the whole team. If the application crashes at the customer sites, the big bosses will have a very bad view about the whole team. You can inform them that there are real consequences for them when the managers do the annual review for each team member. That will likely give them the incentives to fix bugs.

Answer (score 31):

**Because most companies handle initiative on non-core things poorly**

Most people in a new job take initiative one or two times and then stop because they got poor results. I would argue that initiative is only rewarded under niche circumstances in most companies.

1. **You touched it, so if anything goes wrong, it is your fault.**

Companies have this bad habit of basically wanting to make any initiative standalone and wanting to put off risk.  As soon as something goes wrong, they then blame the person who touched it, even if that person's actions had nothing to do with why something actually went wrong.

Proximity is often 90% of blame.

How does getting in trouble work at your company? Is it whoever touched a system last or sent the last email that gets hit with a stick?

2. **Many things which need to be done are punished by bad systems.**

I know a guy who spent a ton of time becoming an expert on certain legacy systems at his company. He bothered to understand the code, find the root causes of errors, and was willing to enthusiastically work on crusty old code that had been hacked together by over a decade of developers.

He was rewarded with not getting a raise because he was not contributing to new projects, so nobody knew what his value was and a new manager arrived who had no idea what he did other than "keep old things running." Was he able to get on new projects? No, as he had become excellent at fixing the old projects so all that work was being assigned to him.

Is excellence in updating/maintenance rewarded at your organization? Or do people care more about those who work on the flashy new stuff?

3. **A lot of management systems erase non-client driven work.**

Any system which primarily measures project progress and success on the basis of what the end-user sees (most non-pure engineering projects) is a project management methodology that is prone to pushing aside anything that the user cannot see.

For example, my organization uses Scrum. What management/product owners see is the Scrum taskboard. The only things on there are those which go on the project. If it isn't on the taskboard, nothing ever happens with it. For example, our test runner has been down for months. Unless we find a week where there is nothing to do and no higher up wants features built, that is never getting fixed. Why? If we spend too much time and it delays a feature, we lose pace.

Is something else crowding out all the work you want them to do? Updating libraries is a big and messy task. I wouldn't commit to that without previously allocated time. Same with bugs. **These things should be time budgeted for and assigned, not hopefully fixed on the side.**

4. **"Excellent. Here is more of the exact same work."**

A good friend of mine automated his entire reporting job using SQL. He then told his manager. His manager just did not hire the other intern job and gave it to my friend, where it was the same manual reporting.

The old automation "broke" and he spent the rest of the co-op term doing nothing but learning data science and applying to scholarships. There was no value to doing anything beyond collecting a paycheque.

5. **They lack faith in management.**

This story is actually from yesterday. Some managers get mad when problems are brought to them. A friend knows one on another team who will scream at anyone who brings her one problem more than he had planned to handle that day.

You do that once and you will spend the next 6 months with your staff not being able to handle issues because they are worried you will get mad and thus will hide bad news or problems they cannot immediately provide a solution for.

That company just lost a major client because they couldn't deliver on a feature in time due to a lack of resources. The team refused to tell the manager about the delay because of her short fuse. Perhaps your team members are not able to fix the problems themselves, but do not have enough faith that you will help them.

6. **Expectations management and form filling.**

Was recently introduced to a new one. Sometimes one department will decline to help another department not because they can't but rather because they don't want to give the impression that they can be relied on to provide that help in the future and nobody can decide who the work should be billed to even if the people are otherwise not doing anything. Sometimes it can just get snarling in an inability to report it in the various reporting forms.

**All things being equal, people will do the right thing.** But in most companies, there are strong incentives to not be responsible for certain unpleasant tasks or to ignore things which are going wrong.

Comment: These are all possible reasons, but as someone who currently has a similar problem, I see one more. Initiative taking is a personality trait. There are people who are proactive and these who need to be motivated even to do the very basics. In my case, none of your possible causes applies. We are in an environment that rewards initiative and she knows that. Her initiative is expected on her projects and she definitely doesn't have too many, the opposite is true. But she simply doesn't care. She likes doing the same thing repeatedly and slowly. Initiative would mean breaking this routine.

Comment: @BigMadAndy, it may be a personality trait amongst some - and in some routine jobs you want people who just plod - but for most people work is just not a place they see as appropriate to demonstrate the initiative they possess. Many managers reserve the right of control and coordination for themselves, and despite managers who loudly bemoan lack of initiative, I've seen initiative punished in practice far more often than I've seen it rewarded, because bosses don't want workers organising their own work.

Comment: @Steve, I've also seen initiative punished and I've been on the receiving end of that many times. But yes, there are people who prefer doing routine work. Showing initiative is always psychologically risky, even in environments that reward it: someone may think your idea is silly, frown at you, etc. Some people don't want that. Not to mention that initiative requires some thinking. Some people simply don't care enough about their jobs to do more than enough not to get fired. Some lack the necessary critical skills.

Comment: I agree with #1 of your answer. If you change large code set, then whatever bugs, known or unknown, will be planted right on you. So if you made some process work better, but also exposed a bug previously unseen, then they would associate that bug to your code regardless. Reverting it back could possibly mean you had to have altered something because it was "working before." So a lot of folks want to avoid this.I myself been a victim of this several times and after a number of meetings and demonstration, the end result was, "Revert and fix it."

Answer (score 7):

This is a very broad question, I will try to give a broad answer.

There are only *very* few people not intrinsically motivated to do a good job, whatever their job is. I have met exactly *one* in my entire life and that person was so not interested in their (or any) job, that they'd certainly not be on SE, a not read a reddit that has the word "job" in it or even do something as a hobby that is close to their job.

So something took the initiative out of your team. Something *made* them turn their backs and not care. Most of the time, that obscure something is the way they are managed. Whether it's the system that sucks or the personality of the manager or both, something has *taught them* that showing initiative is not worth it.

Nobody stands up in the morning thinking "today, let's suck at my job". Many might get up and plan to do the minimum they can get away with and still get paid, but even inside this minimum, everything else being equal, they'd rather do a good job than a bad.

So something has happened in the past that lets your team think they'd rather not care, than care and face the consequences.

It's your job to find out what happened and how to restore a system where caring about one's job is to everyone's benefit.

That might take a while, even if you do it right. Trust does not come back over night.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible your code has suffered too much from technical debt that your team has decided it's just not worth it.  Like, if you have an application using Java 4 with SOAP endpoints, your team probably isn't interested in doing the upgrade to Java 12 and changing over to REST "just because".  That type of thing is A LOT of work and needs to be properly managed and scoped.

Likewise, if your application has too many interdependencies, then bug fixing becomes complicated.  What if you "fix" a "bug", but then it turns out that "bug" was actually a "feature" that was advertised to your consumers and your consumers have built their code relying on that "bug"?  Now you've gone and broken someone else's code.  This is true even if your consumers are yourself; now you've "fixed" a "bug" in your application, but "broken" maybe 5-10 others of your own applications, so now what do you do?  This is why fixing bugs has to be done very carefully in legacy systems of really any meaningful size, and why you don't just "do it" without scoping and considering it.

You should encourage your team to point out issues when they see them, such as technical debt and bugs, and create tickets in your backlog to fix those issues.  However, randomly "fixing" things without considering the impact is not a good idea for a system of nontrivial size.

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad of a question to answer here and we are the wrong people to be answering it.

Instead, it is time to dig into the history and psychology of this team. I recommend bringing it up one on one with members of the team and ask *them* why this behavior is happening. You may find that there are lingering personality issues or prior management issues. You state that you are a few months into the job which means that there was a manager prior to you. Are team members still reacting to that manager's behavior?

Secondly, the question of priorities must be raised internally. There may be valid business reasons to push some bug fixes and updates out for years. I recommend keeping track of these issues, but find out what the business priorities are before making too big of an issue of any single bug or update.

Thirdly, once you have some idea of why, then bring the problem up to the team in team meetings as a problem for the team to solve. This could be a "make or break" issue for the team. In which case, the team needs to solve this, not you alone. It could be that if the team is not willing to solve this problem, then the team will be replaced - either by you or your replacement when you have not gotten the team to solve this.